# Eclipse CDT and lib

Tags: eclipse-cdt, plugins

Below I m mentioning what is my requirement.

In my project Understand’s API were used. Using that APIs I was able to open database, close it, list the names of  a project , list the names of functions in a file n so on.

Understand provided a udb.lib for that which I will be including.  But in Eclipse CDT, there are plug-ins no lib. I need the library so that I can access the APIs.

But I don’t knw how to find and where to get.

With plug-ins can I get the APIs…?

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F .  You shouldn't need any plug-in for this.